# Form validation from complete novice

Tags: forms, validation

After quite a few Google searches, I have finally found my way here for this question.  If this is something that could be better asked elsewhere, any direction that could be provided would be greatly appreciated.

I have made some HTML forms in the past, but I am trying to do some validation, of which, I have never done before.

What I would like to do is have a form that has two drop down lists that are sort of tied together, the first being one of two choices (say A and B) and the other being a list of the numbers 1 through 30.

What I need to do is have 30 of such "questions" and I need to validate that each number (1 through 30) are used in the form and only used once.

As stated I am a novice at any type of the programming required to make such a form from scratch.  I can read some code and understand what is going on sometimes, but I don't have the knowledge to be 100% sure.

Any help, or direction to where I could get this answered is greatly appreciated.

Thank you